# Is Index on table used if I search only on one column while the clustered index is present on multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sqlperformance, database-indexes

Lets say I have a sql table `deadpool` with following columns

```
cisid       int
afid        int
ccid        int
entity      int
dtime       int
guid        uniqueidentifier
addFlags    int
```

Index is present on

```
cisid, afid, ccid
```

Now I have a delete command that deletes rows from `Deadpool` with where clause on `afid` and `ccid`

```
DELETE  FROM deadpool
     FROM    @tempT AS temp
     WHERE   temp.afid= StylinInfoTemp.afid
         AND temp.ccid= StylinInfoTemp.ccid
```

Will Index created on A, B and C used here? How can I verify if index is being used or not?

Query Plan :

```
  DELETE  FROM deadpool FROM    @tempT AS temp   WHERE   temp.afid = deadpool.afid    AND temp.ccid = deadpool.ccid
       |--Clustered Index Delete(OBJECT:([Magneto].[dbo].[deadpool].[deadpool_cis_afid_ccid_PK]))
            |--Nested Loops(Left Semi Join, WHERE:(@tempT.[afid] as [temp].[afid]=[Magneto].[dbo].[deadpool].[afId] AND @temp.[ccid] as [tmptbl].[ccid]=[Magneto].[dbo].[deadpool].[ccid]))
                 |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([Magneto].[dbo].[deadpool].[deadpool_cis_afid_ccidd_PK]))
                 |--Table Scan(OBJECT:(@tempT AS [temp]))
```

Comment: You can see it in the query plan

Comment: @Wouter How do I check query plan? Noob here please help

Comment: In management studio: Query - Display Estimated Execution Plan

Comment: So the index isn't being used in any meaningful sense. For every row in deadpool it is doing a scan of the table variable to see if a corresponding row exists and then if so deleting it. How many rows are actually in `deadpool` and how many rows in `@tempT`?

Comment: But we do see `Index Scan(OBJECT:([Magneto].[dbo].[deadpool]` scanning in Index, how do you say that `isn't being used in any meaningful sense` TempT contains a lot less row compared to deadpool

Comment: The clustered index **is** the table. It is just being used as a repository of rows to scan. The fact that they happen to be in a particular key order is irrelevant to the current execution plan as it is reading them all anyway.

Comment: The expected answer to the question " How many rows are actually in deadpool and how many rows in @tempT? " is two numbers

Comment: deadpool has more than 100k rows while tempt has around 100 rows. I still didn't get the part  `happen to be in a particular key order is irrelevant to the current execution plan as it is reading them all anyway.`

Comment: I suggest you read up on SQL Server execution plans to understand the basics then. I don't see what is difficult to understand about that comment but it may be clearer to you then.

Comment: It's just doing a full scan of both tables, this is not how an index is supposed to be used, as I explained on [dba.se] what appears to be your other account https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/314413/220697

Answer (score 0):

> Will Index created on A, B and C [be] used here?

If the index is on key columns `A,B,C` in that order and you do an equality seek on `A` and `C` the best that can be done in terms of an index seek is a seek on `A` and then read all the index entries matching that part of the predicate and evaluate the `C` part as a residual predicate.

> How can I verify if index is being used or not?

You need to look at the execution plan and see if an operator is referencing the index or not. If there is such an operator you then need to see if it is doing a scan or a seek. If it is doing a seek it will only be doing so on the A column if you look at the properties of the seek so may end up reading a lot more rows than eventually qualify once the C condition is checked

Comment: How do I verify if the index is actually being used or not?

Comment: You need to look at the execution plan and see if an operator is referencing the index or not. If there is such an operator you then need to see if it is doing a scan or a seek. If it is doing a seek it will only be doing so on the A column if you look at the properties of the seek so may end up reading a lot more rows than eventually qualify once the C condition is checked